# Why isn't Quirrell considered a horcrux?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux

Since a part of Voldemort is within Quirrell, doesn't that make him a horcrux by definition as well?

Comment: No. A Horcrux houses part of a split off soul. Quirrel was possessed

Comment: Harry wasn't a Horcrux by definition either, though to many intents and purposes he functioned as one.

Answer (score 1):

Quirrell is considered a horcrux. However, the reason it is not always mentioned is because he was a temporary one and as the first one to be destroyed, the connection is never made in the books, but by definition Quirrell is in fact a horcrux.

> "Quirrell is, in effect, turned into a temporary Horcrux by Voldemort."
>
> ([Here](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-quirrell) is a direct source for which this is stated, you can read more of it from the link.)

Comment: I don't think that JKR was trying to say Quirrell actually was a hurcrux, just that he functioned similar to one.